# Joi when sibling then add extra rules at root

Tags: joi

I have a complex validation which changes depending on the a value in the JSON.

```
{ type: 'a', thing: 1, foo: 'abc' }
{ type: 'b', thing: 2, bar: 123 }
```

I want to validate that if the type is a, then use one set of siblings, if b then use another set of siblings

I would like to use the [when switch](https://hapi.dev/family/joi/?v=16.0.1#anywhencondition-options), but cant work out how to do this at the root.

```
Joi.object({
  type: Joi.string().valid('a','b').required(),
  thing: Joi.number().required()
}).when('type', {
  switch: [
    { is: 'a', then: Joi.object({ foo: Joi.string() }) },
    { is: 'b', then: Joi.object({ bar: Joi.number() }) },
  ],
  otherwise: Joi.forbidden(),
});
```

However this gives the following error:

> Error: Invalid reference exceeds the schema root: ref:type

This kinda makes sense as an error but I don't know how to restructure this to get it to apply the selector at the root.

Im using latest JOI (16.0.1)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This can be resolved by prefixing the key name passed to `.when()`  with a `.`, to denote the key as being relative to the object being validated:

```
Joi.object({
  type: Joi.string().valid('a','b').required(),
  thing: Joi.number().required()
})
.when('.type', {  /* <-- prefix with . */
  switch : [
    { is: 'a', then: Joi.object({ foo: Joi.string() }) },
    { is: 'b', then: Joi.object({ bar: Joi.number() }) },]
})
```

Here's [a working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-form-joi-example-it0rg) - hope that helps :-)

Comment: Awesome thats exactly what i was missing, thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome, long time no see! Hope all's well at company X :)

Comment: Haha yeah all going well, busy as usual, you should come along to /dev/talk sometime and catch up

Comment: Nice - ah yeah, a couple of people have mentioned that to me now. Will definitely make a point of coming along sometime soon :)